# LCH Similarity - Need Same POS? Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, similarity, wordnet

Comparing wordnet similarity measures to see which is most relevant/useful to my corpus - came across this error message when trying to compute lch -

"Computing the lch similarity requires Synset('home'.n.01) and Synset('chronological.a.01') to have the same part of speech."

Do I have to normalize all words in my list to be the same POS before attempting lch?

For reference, I was able to compute [wup_similarity](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) successfully without any POS normalization. The list of words I am trying to calculate similarity have all been lemmatized using [WordNetLemmatizer](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html?highlight=wordnetlemmatizer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't fix this by changing part of speech, since not all words can be any part of speech. "chronological" can't be a noun, for example.

One approach is to catch exceptions like this, or to check for different parts of speech, and assign a similarity of zero.

WordNet also handles this sometimes by simulating a shared root across different parts of speech, which is probably why some of your similarity measures worked. However, the way that works [is confusing](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1023), so you probably shouldn't rely on it.

If you want similarity for arbitrary words, try using word vectors (Word2Vec or GloVe) instead of WordNet.